# Does this function using arrow functions if not what's m=> m>n means

Tags: javascript, function

In this function what does `m => m > n` means?

I think "m arrow m greater than n" is arrow function but where is 
function 
declaration before it.

```
function greaterThan(n) {
  return m => m > n;
}
let greaterThan10 = greaterThan(10);
console.log(greaterThan10(1));
```

Comment: That is just a function returning another (arrow) function. Google *"currying"*.

Answer (score 2):

That is a function which in normal function syntax looks like:

```
function(m){
  if(m > n) return true;
  else return false;
}
```

```js
function greaterThan(n) {
  return function(m){
    if(m > n) return true;
    else return false;
  }
}
let greaterThan10 = greaterThan(10);
console.log(greaterThan10(1));
```

Answer (score 2):

From [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/es6-arrow-functions-new-fat-concise-syntax-javascript/),

> By using arrow functions, we avoid having to type the function keyword, return keyword (it’s implicit in arrow functions), and curly brackets.

So, this line,

```
let greaterThan10 = greaterThan(10);
```

is equivalent to,

```
let greaterThan10 = m => m > 10;  //n = 10, static value
```

And calling this,

```
console.log(greaterThan10(1));
```

will provide the value of `m` as `1` and result is `false`.

Answer (score 1):

`m => m > n` is the definition of another function.

```js
function(m) {
  return m > n;
}
```

It is equivalent of calling `greaterThan(10)(1)`:

```js
function greaterThan(n) {
  return function(m) {
    return m > n;
  }
}
let greaterThan10 = greaterThan(10);
console.log(greaterThan10(1));
console.log(greaterThan(10)(1));
```